# In PHP GD: How to scale image to certain width, while maintaining its proportions. Then crop the height from the bottom

Tags: php, gd, php-gd

To clarify, I am looking to imitate the following behavior that occurs in HTML/CSS.

```
<div style="width: 260px; height: 174px">
  <img src="path/img.png" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden">  
</div>
```

This causes the width to always be my preferred width, while still maintaining its proportions. It then appears as if the bottom part of the height is getting cut off, since the overflow is set to hidden. I would like to imitate this behavior while using the PHP GD library to generate the image. I apologize in advance if there is an obvious solution to this, but this is what I tried for far too long to avail.

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($uploadfile));
$filename = $uploaddir . '/thumb.png';

$thumb_width = 260;
$thumb_height = 174;

$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);

$original_aspect = $width / $height;
$thumb_aspect = $thumb_width / $thumb_height;

if ( $original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect )
{
  $new_height = $thumb_height;
  $new_width = $width / ($height / $thumb_height);
}
else
{
  $new_width = $thumb_width;
  $new_height = $height / ($width / $thumb_width);
}

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

imagecopyresampled($thumb, $image,
               0, 0,
               0, -$thumb_height,
               $new_width, $new_height,
               $width, $height);
imagepng($thumb, $filename, 5);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read your question as: the thumbnail shall always have a width of 260px (even if the original has < 260px); and the height shall be at max 174px; but it could be less, according to the aspect ratio.
Let's start by making the target width and the maximum height constants instead of variables.

```
define('THUMB_WIDTH', 260);
define('THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT', 174);
```

You already know the width, no need to calculate it and to assign it to $new_height, it's just THUMB_WIDTH.
But you need to know the scaling factor, which is `THUMB_WIDTH / imagesx($image)` (quick test: image width is 520 -> scaling factor=0.5, seems ok).
Now you calculate the $height given the scaling factor, `$height=imagesy($image)*scaling`=>`$height=imagesy($image)*THUMB_WIDTH/imagesx($image)`.
But this could be too large. You want whatever is smaller, either THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT or $height =>

```
$thumb_height = min(
    THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT,
    $height
);
```

Then create a resource for an image THUMB_WIDTH x $height px
and resample the complete image, letting gd handle the cropping.

So the complete script would be (without error handling and completely untested)

```
<?php
define('THUMB_WIDTH', 260);
define('THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT', 174);

$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($uploadfile));

$height = (int)ceil(imagesy($image) * THUMB_WIDTH / imagesx($image)); // (THUMB_WIDTH / imagesx($image)) being the scaling factor
$thumb_height = min(
    THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT,
    $height 
);

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( THUMB_WIDTH, $thumb_height);

imagecopyresampled(
    $thumb, $image,
    0, 0, // dest
    0, 0, // src
    THUMB_WIDTH, $height, // dest width/height - just draw the complete image, let gd handle the cropping
    imagesx($image), imagesy($image) // src width/height
);
imagepng($thumb);
```

Comment: Version #1 was obviously wrong.... and this one probably has a stupid mistake in it, too ....

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I think you misunderstood me though. I am looking to scale the width to exactly 260px, with the height being irrelevant for scaling purposes (other than being the correct amount in order to maintain the correct image proportion). AFTER it is scaled, I am looking to basically chop off any extra height from the bottom that is greater than 174px. So if I scale a picture, the dimensions could be width: 260px and height: 190px. I am looking to crop the extra 16px from the height, so it essentially chops it off from the bottom

Comment: Yes, I understood. The script is supposed to do that. Have you tried it and it failed?

Comment: Ah, I actually have a working php_gd extension module. I've tested the script with an image 520x344 and it was scaled down to 260x172 correctly. And one image 805x944 which was scaled and cropped to 260x174 - also apparently with the correct aspect ratio.